# python - How can I convert parent - child relationship into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

The code so far is:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in dirs:
        if directory.endswith("GUI"): # Get only folders that end with GUI
            print "Parent is: ", (os.path.join(root, directory))
            os.chdir(os.path.join(root, directory))
            for file in glob.glob("*.b"): # Get only files that end with b
                  print "Child is: ", (file)
                  dictionaryParentChild[directory] = file
return dictionaryParentChild
```

Current: This code return only 1 parent: 1 child
Desired: The code should return 1 parent: many children

Answer (score 1):

```
def dir_files_map(start_dir):
    import os
    dd = {}
    # create dictionary where the key is folder root path
    # and the values are the files in that folder
    # filter files based on endswiths(string) clause
    for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(start_dir):
        for f in filenames:
            if f.endswith('.b'):
               dd.setdefault(root,[]).append(f)
    return dd
```

Comment: I did not know about `dict.setdefault` method, nice alternative to `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

replace `dictionaryParentChild[directory] = file`

with

```
if directory not in dictionaryParentChild:
   dictionaryParentChild[directory] = [file]
else:
   dictionaryParentChild[directory].append(file)
```

or event better replace the entire inner for loop with

```
dictionaryParentChild[directory] = [file for file in glob.glob("*.b")]
```